# Integrating PV (protein viewer) with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to integrate [PV (protein viewer)](https://biasmv.github.io/pv/) with React but can't do so, tried searching and I think I'm the first to do so. Although I followed the guide [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)I still cant make it work.

So far here is what I came up with.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class pv extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.el = this.pvDiv
    this.viewer = pv.Viewer(this.el, { width : 'auto', height : 'auto', antialias : true })
    this.viewer.on('viewerReady', function() {
        console.log('ready!')
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div ref={el => this.pvDiv = el}/>
        </div>
    );
  }

}

export default pv;
```

Comment: is the `console.log` logging ? and are you importing `pv` object anywhere or is it done globally using `<script>` tag ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you are calling your component class `pv` while you already have a global `pv` in scope, which can cause problems.

If you read it carefully, your guide tells you to do

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.el = $(this.pvDiv);
  ...
}
```

where `$` is jQuery, for example `import $ from 'jquery';`. Does it work with that change?

Then you should look at any error logs in the dev tools console of your browser, where "ready!" should appear if it works. If it does not, print the value of `this.viewer` to make sure it gets constructed.

It is likely that you may see "ready!" but nothing on screen, as you haven't specified any protein to visualize.